# SQL Insert not working with Multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query to update based on 4 WHERE conditions. When I execute this I get 0 records updated. I am confused because there is a record the meets these conditions.

Query:

```
UPDATE tp_margins
    SET cost = '139.00',
        updated = '2020-08-03 16:00:53'
 WHERE itemNumber='LATITUDE 5480' AND ff='TOUCH' AND proc='i5' AND category='LAPTOP'
```

If I remove the WHERE ff it does update but all records that match ignoring ff.
here is the Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tp_margins` (
  `margins_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemNumber` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `ff` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proc` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `shipping` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opex` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hdd` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ram` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kbm` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coa` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salePrice` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `updated` varchar(40) DEFAULT '--------'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with this Mysql Update?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Execute: `SELECT * FROM tp_margins WHERE itemNumber='LATITUDE 5480' AND ff='TOUCH' AND proc='i5' AND category='LAPTOP'` to verify that there is a row.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tp_margins WHERE itemNumber='LATITUDE 5480' AND ff='TOUCH' AND proc='i5' AND category='LAPTOP' Does come back with a single row. That works great.

Comment: Returned:
margins_ID
itemNumber
ff
proc
sku
category
cost
shipping
opex
hdd
ram
kbm
coa
salePrice
updated

159
LATITUDE 5480
TOUCH
i5
LT-DELL-5480-I5-256SSD-8GB-TOUCH
LAPTOP
139.00
NULL
NULL
26.00
25.00
NULL
25.00
429.99
2020-08-03 16:00:53

Comment: Note that the rows _affected_ by the update will be reported as zero, if the values you are setting are already the values in that row. I.e. if the update results in no net change to the data, there are zero rows affected.

Comment: As @BillKarwin mentioned the new values that you set are exactly the same as the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will report  "0 rows affected" when the UPDATE statement matches one (or more) rows and the rows to be updated are not actually modified by the UPDATE... that is, if we are setting the columns to the current value.

Test the conditions in the WHERE clause in a SELECT statement.

Then for the rows returned, check the current value of the columns to be updated.

We could test the UPDATE with a value that does actually change the value in the column, and then change it back to what we want it to be. (We should also mention that the UPDATE statement will fire any before/after update TRIGGERs, in case the effect of the triggers matters.)

---

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html

"For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually changed. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by the WHERE clause."

Comment: IS there a way to check both if a value is null and also is equal to?  ff is null or ff ="TOUCH"

Comment: @JasonBrashear:  just like that, but override the order of precedence of AND and OR using parens ...   `WHERE ... AND ( ff='TOUCH' OR ff IS NULL ) AND proc='i5' AND ...` ... alternatively, we could use an expression that converts NULL to 'TOUCH' or vice versa e.g. `... AND IFNULL(ff,'TOUCH') = 'TOUCH' AND ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a row.  You can start with looking for the matches:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM tp_margins m
WHERE m.itemNumber = 'LATITUDE 5480' AND m.proc = 'i5' AND m.category = 'LAPTOP' AND
      m.ff = 'TOUCH'
```

When that returns nothing, you have to ask why.  I would recommend using `LIKE` to see what similar values are there:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM tp_margins m
WHERE m.itemNumber = 'LATITUDE 5480' AND m.proc = 'i5' AND m.category = 'LAPTOP' AND
      m.ff LIKE '%TOUCH%'
```

There can be reasons why strings look the same but are different.  The most common are:

- Leading spaces.
- Invisible characters.
- Look-alike characters (such as lower-case L and the number one).

Note that you seem to intend `updated` as a date/time.  It should be declared as such.  In fact, in MySQL, you can have it update automatically when the row is updated.

Comment: When I run your First query the record is returned. When I run the 2nd select query the record is returned. IT is only when I try to update based on the same exact conditions I get nothing. Still very confused.

Comment: The "0 rows affected" means there were no rows actually changed; it doesn't necessarily mean that no rows were matched.

Comment: @JasonBrashear . . . In addition, `update` queries do not return anything.